# CSS Waiting Bar? Styling

Tags: css

I want to know if it's possible to style the bar http://puu.sh/3LSN8.png in that picture (in the textarea).

I have no idea what it's called but it flashes and it's the bar showing where your text is at.

Thanks.

Comment: caret ?  take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339333/styling-text-input-caret

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called a [**caret**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_navigation) and there is no way to style it using CSS, as its behavior is decided by the browser.

You can use Javascript, however, to achieve a **fake**y result.