# Get position - and follow - text box cursor

Tags: javascript, css

I am currently trying to create a text box with a custom cursor. Is this possible? Can the text box text cursor be tracked in anyway?

**EDIT**
My apologies: not enough info. I understand you can change the mouse cursor with css. What I am trying to achieve is a custom cursor for the blinking text cursor, within the text box.

Comment: It is possible, google docs shows cursors for all the users that have the doc open. However, they implemented everything at a very low level, the cursor is a div, and there's a lot of tracking required. That's what you'd have to do, there's no easy way

Comment: Thanks. Any clue where to start? I really haven't the slightest on trying to track a cursor like that.

Comment: Read the KK's answer... You can change the cursor within a textbox using `textbox:hover{cursor: url(images/my-cursor.png), auto;}`

Comment: @EricWu Did you even read the question? Not the mouse cursor, the blinking text cursor. Ricky, there are a million ways you could do it. We can't possibly show it to you in a QA forum. You should try it yourself and create a separate question for each problem you encounter. SO is not really for asking people how to do something, it's for asking why something doesn't work the way you expect it.

Comment: Sorry, @JuanMendes, apparently, I didn't. Obviously _trying to create a text box with a custom cursor_ is not what my code shows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: As per the revised question from OP.

As far the `caret` design is concerned, you can try this demo : http://shachi.prophp.org/demo.html

Tutorial: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?p=74576#post74576

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7339406/2000051

Comment: @JuanMendes Thanks for the comment, modified the answer accordingly.