# How to set thickness of a blinking cursor inside input-box ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am not sure if it possible to set thickness width of the blinking cursor.
If so, what is the most efficient way to do that ?

I have :

`<input autofocus id="searchbox" placeholder="Enter Catalog # " type="text" />`

[image]

I just want to **bold** it if that possible.

Comment: Well, I guess I am out of luck :(  thanks - anyway

Comment: too bad the question is closed , i had some answer possible , i gave an answer out there with a snippet http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339333/styling-text-input-caret/28818592#28818592 idea is to use animation and bg gradient

Comment: http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/OPwPOr demo