# How to change default color of caret on iOS for inputs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css, caret

Is there any way to change blue colored caret on iOS for inputs?

[image]

**UPDATE:** So caret-color property will fix this 'issue' when it will be supported in ios. check browser support when you are here in the future https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-caret-color

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: no Genti I think its not possible to do that yet

Comment: Thanks for replying. I must implement my own caret component for iOS then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[caret-color](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/caret-color) property is finally [supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-caret-color) in ios so now you can change the color of the caret.

```css
input {
  font-size: 20px;
  caret-color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the compatibility of `-webkit-text-fill-color` is, but if that is acceptable for compatibility you can use a combination of that, text-shadow, color, and background-color with css to create the desired input. No JS is required.

This basis for this approach was described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30031723/1026459

The blue can be hard to see (if you change it to white it is a little more obvious).

```css
input{
  color: #456ce1;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px red;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background-color: #272b36;
}
```

```html
<input value = "CHCJ"/>
```

Don't forget to focus the input field with your mouse.

Comment: Thanks for your response Travis. I know about this snippet but unfortunately  it doesnt work for me  on iphones.