# Styling the caret in an input text area

Tags: javascript, html, css, caret

I came across a website that used styling on the caret for an input text field. I've never seen this before but it looks really nice. I've done a ton of research but there doesn't seem to be a lot of information on how to do it. Please see gif below:

[image]

How do you change the colour and height of a caret?

For reference the website is betterment.com.

Comment: this is the default caret, you should see the related css

Comment: You can change the colour of the caret with the input styles like the answer from @Lamar, but if you're looking for something more complex then the answer is in this [stackoverflow thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339333/styling-text-input-caret)

Comment: the 'caret' follow the same styling which you five to the `input` field, for more clear explanation visit this http://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/o7cmvv28/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it the same style as the input itself (color, font-size, etc..) ?
Here it is green.
[image]