# overlay 2 divs and a textarea

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, z-index

The code snippet and the related issue can be found [here on github](https://github.com/ishankhare07/syntax-highlighter/issues/3)
is the text area the root cause of the problem?
I have also tried using `<div contenteditable> </div>` instead of `<textarea></textarea>`

> EDIT: copying question here

```
<div id="caret"></div>
```

[at line 25](https://github.com/ishankhare07/syntax-highlighter/blob/gh-pages/static/html/index.html#L25) in `index.html` needs to be put on `z-index: 2` in order to come between the [background div](https://github.com/ishankhare07/syntax-highlighter/blob/gh-pages/static/html/index.html#L22) and the [front textarea](https://github.com/ishankhare07/syntax-highlighter/blob/gh-pages/static/html/index.html#L24)
instead the caret comes after the front textarea at the bottom, even explicitly positioning the caret div doesn't make it move to the right place

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-K1qjQ+NcF2TYO/eI3M6v8EiNYZfA95pQumfvcVrTHtwQVDG+aHRqLi/ETn2uB+1JqwYqVG3LIvdm9lj6imS/pQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://raw.github.com/ishankhare07/syntax-highlighter/blob/gh-pages/static/css/index.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://raw.github.com/ishankhare07/syntax-highlighter/blob/gh-pages/static/js/app.js"></script>

<div class="container top-offset" ng-controller="EntryController as highlighter">
  <div class="row top-buffer">
    <input placeholder="Enter filename with extension" ng-model="highlighter.filename" class="rounded-border col-md-6">
    <div class="col-md-6 text-center">{{ highlighter.filename }}</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row top-buffer panel panel-default" id="code">
    <div class="code highlight" id="background">
    </div>
    <textarea spellcheck="false" class="code panel-default" id="front" ng-change="highlighter.change()" ng-model="highlighter.code"></textarea>
    <div id="caret">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a poor quality question. Just think how many will do the work to set up a test case were the problem is showing? I won't do it. Please put some more effort into your question. Make a test case on jsfiddle.net or codepen,io or the like. Just the bounty is not a big enough lure.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, i totally agree that i failed to explain my problem correctly and took your suggestion to try it out on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ishankhare07/uo6q5v5y/7/). I managed to get everything working, so it turns out that there was some css mess-up that i was doing.

Comment: Please update your question's snippet with the fiddle. Also, did you check this question? I think it doing exactly what do you want. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339333/styling-text-input-caret

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the feedback, i totally agree that i failed to explain my problem correctly and took your suggestion to try it out on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ishankhare07/uo6q5v5y/7/). I managed to get everything working, so it turns out that there was some css mess-up that i was doing.

> html

```
<body ng-app="highlighter">
    <div class="container borders" ng-controller="ColorController as color">
        <div id="background" class="borders expand overlay text-padding">
            {{ color.code }} voila!
        </div>
        <div id="caret" class="borders expand overlay text-padding">
            {{ color.caretText }}
        </div>
        <textarea id="text" class="borders expand overlay text-padding" ng-model="color.code" ng-change="color.change()">
        </textarea>
    </div>
</body>
```

> js

```
var app = angular.module("highlighter",[]);

app.controller('ColorController', function () {
    this.code = "";
    this.caretText = "";
    this.caret = "&#x2588;";

    var whitespaces = [" ", "\t", "\n", "\v", "\r"];

    this.change = function() {
        this.caretText = "";
        angular.element(document.querySelector('#caret')).html(this.caretText)
        for(var i=0; i < this.code.length; i++) {
            if(whitespaces.indexOf(this.code[i]) != -1) {
                // is a whitespace
                this.caretText += this.code[i];
            } else {
                this.caretText += " ";
            }
        }

        this.caretText += this.caret;

angular.element(document.querySelector('#caret')).html(this.caretText)
        console.log(this.caretText);
    };
});
```

> css

```
.borders {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: aqua;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.expand {
    padding: 10%;
    height: 80vh;
    width: 90vw;
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20vh;
}

#background {
    z-index: 1;
}

#caret {
    z-index: 2;
    color: rgba(250,80,150, 0.5);
    white-space: pre;
}

#text {
    z-index: 3;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

.text-padding {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family: monospace;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand your question. As far as I can tell you just want your caret div to be on z-index:2.

So in the CSS

```
#caret {
    z-index:2;
}
```

If this was not what you are looking for, Then please update your question to a proper question with a jsfiddle link.

Answer (score 1):

I'm kinda confused about your topic but here's a div text editor made in java with local storage

```html
<html>
</head>
<body>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="opensheet.css" />
<h1>SCRAPS.txt</h1>
<div class="notepad" contentEditable="true"></div>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zepto/1.0rc1/zepto.min.js "></script>
<script>
$( function() {
var ls = window.localStorage


if (ls.getItem('data')) {
$('.notepad').text(ls.getItem('data'));
}


$('.notepad').blur( function() {
ls.setItem('data', $('.notepad').text() );
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```