# How can I change the input cursor/caret color?

Tags: html, css, input

I want to achieve such features:（for the `<input>` node）

1. the color of placeholder text is: `#b8b9b9`
2. the color of the text you input is: `#4e5050`
3. the color of the input caret is: `#FF0000`

I have already achieved the first two feature 1 and 2,the code is:

```css
input[type='text']::-webkit-input-placeholder{
  color: #b8b9b9;
}
input[type='text']:-moz-placeholder{
  color: #b8b9b9;
}
input[type='text']::-moz-placeholder{
  color: #b8b9b9;
}
input[type='text']:-ms-input-placeholder{
  color: #b8b9b9;
}
input[type='text']:focus {
  color: #4e5050;
}
```

But I do not know how to achieve the feature-3.

I have already tried the function at [Styling text input caret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339333/styling-text-input-caret),
but this doesn't work for the mobile safari browser. The mobile safari input caret color is already the default color of the iphone:blue

Comment: already have a answer for this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339333/styling-text-input-caret

Comment: Thanks,but it doesn't work for the mobile safari browser

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you can assign an image to any element for cursor by this option

```
div {
   cursor: url(YOUR_IMAGE_URL), auto;
}
```

Comment: if I assign an image has the fixed width and height,when I change the input height,the cursor image height will fit for the input node height?

Comment: `cursor` is for the **mouse pointer**, if I understand you correctly, you are looking for the  **caret** ([The blink line](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lPX6Z.jpg)) color.

Comment: yeah,the caret color

Answer (score 7):

Use modern CSS!

```
input {
    caret-color : #FF0000;
}
```