# Ionic3: Change cursor color in input fields

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic3

How can I change the color of the cursor for text-input-fields in my Ionic 3 app on android (or however to call the marker that lets you move to a desired position in some text)?
As you can see from the following screenshot, the cursor is currently green. In other Input-fields it is blue. I want to change it to my primary color.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/yTc6QZT.png]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is possible by CSS I had implemented this long ago, not sure this blog was  the same blog that I referenced but it might help https://gist.github.com/JoeKeikun/72718f5faaf518304024

Comment: Thanks, @vaibhavmaster. Unfortunately, this doesn't work.

Comment: Does this work ?  input {
     color: blue;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
input::-webkit-input-placeholder,
{
    color:
    text-shadow: none;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: yellow;
}

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately it doesn't @Vega.

Comment: webkit is ioS/Apple stuff - op asked for Android.

Answer (score 1):

BTW: What type of input are you talking about?

```
<ion-input> 
<ion-searchbar>
<input>
```

There was also this post on [caret's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41993055/495157) because you said cursor. This was admittedly [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/caret-color) focused, There is a [W3C draft](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-ui/#insertion-caret) for this. The CSS **caret-color**

You might also check out **src/theme/variables.scss** in your project explorer
And [here in the documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/overriding-ionic-variables/)
But I suspect that might not yield much.
Filtering based on search terms of 'input','color', or 'md' in the documentation, would be my stab at it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The screenshot is an `<ion-searchbar>`. However, the same issue occurs when using an`<ion-input>`. I didn't try `<input>`, but I guess it's going to be the same there.

I already checked the documentation and the available variables to override, however I didn't find anything.

Thank you anyway. Doesn't seem as easy as I thought. I just expected that it would be normal behaviour to just use the primary color for this.

Comment: The type of element was in case there was something that SASS variables targeted specifically. But since we're talking about caret/cursor it probably was unfortunately moot.

Answer (score 1):

Just use CSS for that search input i.e caret-color
Follow this link for more details [CSS caret-color](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/caret-color)

Answer (score 1):

In case Anyone is looking for the answer:

In the browser you can use 'caret-color: red' over the '.item-inner' class inside the input, but in Android and IOS wont work.

The way to do it for them is in the .input class like this:

```
input {
  color: rgb(60, 0, 248);  /* change [input cursor color] by this*/
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #D60B0B; /* change [input font] by this*/
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent; //This changes the color of the text in the input
}
```

This solution comes from this links: https://gist.github.com/JoeKeikun/72718f5faaf518304024

Hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your input:

```
caret-color: #ffffff;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for that green line fix, then you can work around outline/border color, so my approach would be, on focus

```
#yourInput:focus{
  border-color : blue;
  //outline-color : blue:
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Green line fix? I'm actually talking about the cursor or however to call it properly. Not the input line. I know how to change this ;-)

Comment: Oh.., I didn't catch that, I too will search for it and let you know