# Increase the blinking caret width & height in input field using CSS3 or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Increase the blinking caret's width & height in input field using CSS3 or Javascript?

```html
<input type="text" value="" />
```

Increase the blinking cursor pointer width & height in input field.

Comment: Search for _caret_, not _cursor_....and the closest you can get today is to simulate it using script: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339333/styling-text-input-caret

Answer (score 5):

You can't increase caret `height` and `width`.

There is no css property to do that. But you can change the color of caret.

```
<style>
  input {
    caret-color:red;
  }
</style>
```