# How to CSS the cursor in an input? (The flashing line)

Tags: html, css, cursor

How do I change the CSS of the flashing line cursor in an input?

I know it works to change the mouse pointer with cursor: pointer/text/... but that's not what I mean.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339333/styling-text-input-caret

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to style your cursor pointer inside the text box. To do this you can simply do the following :

HTML

```
<input type='text'/>
```

CSS

```
input,
textarea { // Style for your cursor
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 2px;
    color: blue;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

input::-webkit-input-placeholder,
textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder { // Style for your placeholder 
    color: #ccc;
    text-shadow: none;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: initial;
}
```