# Is there a solution to changing the blinker thickness in input element using modern css styles?

Tags: html, css

About the problem:
The link is the inVision design of an input element with custom css styles.
[image]
As you can see, its border is removed except the bottom line and the cursor/blinker looks pretty thick.

Here's what I have done so far.

```
<input class="custom-input" />

.custom-class {
      border: none;
      border-bottom: #eee solid 3px;
      line-height: 2;
      font-size: 36px;
      text-align: center;
      caret-color: #231F20;
}
```

What is missing so far is that the blinker is still an ordinary one.
I have gone through research to find answers. There are a bunch of articles and StackOverflow answers for caret-color but none of them answers how to change the thickness of it.

Also, there is a codepen demo for using a `span` element by enabling the content to be editable.

But my question is "Is there a solution with only css styles after all the days of evolution in modern css?"

Thanks in advance.

PS. I am not looking for `caret-color` property solutions. I am talking about the thickness of the blinker specifically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Styling text input caret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339333/styling-text-input-caret)

Comment: I couldn't find an answer and gave up doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can modify the text caret thickness (I only see [one related](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/caret#CSS_related_to_the_caret) property), but you can change its color with [`caret-color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/caret-color).

There [seems to be](https://www.google.com/search?&q=windows+10+caret+thickness) some ways to change the caret thickness using OS tools, but none in css for the moment.

**Edit:** There is another way to customize the caret: use js to create a new caret above the classic one ([src](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7339406/6813732) -> [link](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?t=17450), [src2](https://benfrain.com/creating-a-custom-input-cursorcaret/) -> [link2](https://github.com/apm1467/jQuery.Custom-Caret) (jQuery plugin)).

I [forked](https://codepen.io/lmmm/pen/dBwxvj) a [codepen](https://codepen.io/johnchinjew/pen/YpPGpp), and I think you can use the "cutom caret" to hide the authentic one :)

Comment: Yeah, @sodimel. That’s what I have found with bunch of answers but doesn’t answer my question. I am looking for solutions for thickness of the blinker, not its color.