# How to change input cursor width and height

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to change Input cursor width and height

```
<input type="text" value="">
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Styling text input caret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339333/styling-text-input-caret)

Comment: @HarunYilmaz hey thanks for reply, i was looking for something like 3px width, 5px height and with some color like that and i have googled only thing i found is color, but not width and height

Answer (score 0):

To change the width use with `size` :

```
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" size="80">
```

And to change the height use with class in css :

```
<input type="text" class="height "  name=" item" align="left" />
```

In the css :

```
.height  {
    height:30px;
}
```